# Unhandled Exception error when publishing a Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I want to publish a shiny app. Therefore I am using the rsconnect package:

I do the following:

```
rsconnect::setAccountInfo(name='my_name',
                          token='my_token',
                          secret='my_secret_token')

setwd("yourwd")
library(rsconnect)
deployApp()
```

This however gives my the following error:

```
Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 502660937 failed: Error building image: Error fetching shiny (1.0.5.9000) source. <CRANPackageSource repo='http://cran.rstudio.org'> unable to satisfy package: shiny (1.0.5.9000)
In addition: Warning message:
In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
  Failed to infer source for package 'shiny'; using latest available version on CRAN instead
```

Any thoughts on what goes wrong here?